# Why doesn't Chrome make an HTTP request to docs.google.com?

Tags: http, google-chrome

I noticed that Chrome doesn't seem to make an HTTP request to docs.google.com under some circumstances.

What I did, while capturing traffic using Wireshark:

- Visit Google Docs, log in
- Close Tab
- Clear cache (Cache and hosted apps)
- Visit http://docs.google.com/

I cannot find a single HTTP request to docs.google.com, all I see is SSL traffic.

I know that there are technologies like SPDY, Cache manifests and DNS CNAMEs that could interfere, but none comes to my mind that could really make the request disappear, especially after clearing the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All requests to `http://docs.google.com` immediately redirect to `https://docs.google.com/`. This is hardcoded in Chrome and called [HSTS](http://dev.chromium.org/sts).

Comment: How does it "redirect" without using HTTP?

Comment: @AndreKR it's hardcoded in google chrome. in the code of google chrome, and if they wanted to change it, they would have to send a update to everyone. try with firefox.

Comment: @jp_ You can also configure it on `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`. Hard to believe that HSTS is already 10 years old.